# SQL Server Horizontal Partition on DDB

Tags: sql-server, distributed-databases

Hi i need to have three databases each one on one sql server that are on connected by network. The main concern is we need to have horizontal partition for a table by the id,

How do we do that in sql server?

I alreary search for tutorials but only find horizontal partition with file group and thats not posible on Distributed Database

Comment: With multiple on-prem SQL instances, consider a [distributed partitioned view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql). This can be done with or without table partitioning, with each member table having a mutually exclusive check constraint on the primary key.

Comment: How do i make a function or something to constraint the PK ? like for inserts no one have the ID 2 in the other database